# Right pattern to be used in situation where some handlers are independent and some handlers depend on other handlers execution

Tags: design-patterns, chain-of-responsibility

Working on redesigning a system which compute some attributes given input as an object like property.

We are using handlers to compute property related attributes. Each handler takes care of computing single property attribute information.

Problem:
1. There are some handlers which depend on other handler's output (other attribute to be computed first).

Proposed Solution:
I was thinking to use CoR (Chain of responsibility pattern) here. My idea was to use CoR only for the handlers which depend on each other's output.  will invoke other handlers independently.

Is there any other pattern or better way to get the done ?

Don't want to use CoR overall because might in future we will want to run these handlers in parallel which is not possible if i use CoR pattern here.

Have given more thought to problem and found that there could be dependency on multiple handlers.
Problem:
1. Each handler can depend on multiple handler's output (other attribute to be computed first). 
-Solution i can think of is using two buckets "Complete" and "Pending". Keep on executing handlers from pending bucket unless are handlers are executed.

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: This sounds like something more suitable to a decorator pattern.  Of course, a little code example might make it easier to grasp what you need to do.

Comment: What if any handler can depend on multiple handlers ?

I can think of one way where i can have two buckets "completed handlers" and another "pending handlers" and can execute handlers iterative way till all handlers are completed.

Comment: Doesn't change things, but that is even more of an argument against CoR.  This also demonstrates the issue of picking a pattern a priori.  Write some code that solves your issue and see what pattern or patterns suggest themselves.

Comment: thanks dbugger@. Will try but not getting any idea where to start